# Responsive menu not working on WordPress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

As I converted my website to WordPress I realised that my responsive menu stopped working properly.
Instead of hiding the menu and revealing the burger button which should toggle the menu, the ul appears visible at all times and seems unaffected by any of the jquery code. Would anyone happen to have any idea as per how to correct that please?
Thank you all in advance for your attention.

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <a href="#" id="burger_menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  <?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
      'theme_location'  => 'primary',
      'container'       => 'div'
    ));
  ?>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
header nav #burger_menu {
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}

header nav .menu ul {
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
}

header nav .menu ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  /* NAV */
  header nav #burger_menu {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  header nav ul {
    background: rgba(98,194,210,0.85) !important;
    line-height: 10px !important;
  }

  header nav ul,
  nav:active ul {
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    background: #62c2d2;
    right: 0;
    top: 80px;
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
//RESPONSIVE NAV
$('#burger_menu').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('header ul').toggle();
  $('header ul').mouseleave(function() {
    $('header ul').css('display', 'none !important');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding `click event` twice in which first is for showing and second for hiding the menu, so when you click link it will just show then hide immediately so try to use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) like,

```
//RESPONSIVE MENU
$('#burger_menu').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('header nav .menu ul').toggle();
}
```

Comment: Dear Rohan, thank you very much for your help. I took your solution and adjusted it, but however it still does not seem to do anything to it. When resized to a smaller screen the menu appears to be showing (rather than hiding), and nothing happens when I either click on the burger button nor when my mouse leaves the ul.
NOTE: I've updated the jQuery code

Comment: I suggest you to try Bootstrap Framework for Responsiveness See navbars on http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples-navbars

Comment: I use Foundation 6, which also has a responsive menu option, however decided to code it myself for styling preferences, so hopefully I'll manage to fix this, but thank you for the tip though Rohan.

Comment: Ok, for the window resize you need to add event `$(window).on('resize',function(){/**code to show/hide menu*/});` on the basis of `$(window).width()`.

Comment: Yes I tried, but had to remove it as I want it to be applicable to smaller devices without having to manually trigger a window resize event.
But thank you once again for your great advice Rohan.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using the wrong media query. Find the Media Query for a smaller screen or are you just using the one?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px)
```

Also change px to % where applicable.

If you could post a url or a dev url I could  be more helpful.

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out. I do have several screen queries, such as `@media screen and (max-width: 639px)` and `@media screen and (min-width: 1281px)`, but what I don't understand is that it worked fine before converting it to a wordpress menu, so was wandering if there were some wp rules I was unable to overwrite.

Comment: I have no idea without being able to see something, perhaps you were using css and now your using scss - try and change your .css file to .scss You will need to change the code in the 639px for it to be responsive on   >639px screen. The only other thing I can think of blindly is  you may have  been editing it for a while and it saved in your cache - it would have looked correct on your browser.

Comment: In the end I eventually found the issue, which was the fact of playing with `nav ul` display value, rather than using it on `.menu`.
But once again thank you ever so much for your time and attention David, much appreciated.